# How to cancel ajax request using Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I'm using Ajax.ActionLink like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("link text", "action", new AjaxOptions(){ OnBegin = "test()" })
```

I want to be able to cancel the ajax call of the link based on the result of my test() function in javascript, like so

```
function test(){

  if(condition){
    //execute the ajax request 
    return true; 
  }else
  {
    //cancel the ajax request
    return false; 
  }

}
```

I've seen tutorials demonstrating that this is possible, but I somehow can't get it to work.Can someone help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
OnBegin = "test()"
```

to

```
OnBegin = "return test()"
```